# How to get maximum shutter speed in NIKON L820?

Tags: nikon, shutter-speed, point-and-shoot

I have a NIKON L820 camera which is a Point and shoot. It does not have a manual mode. But in its specification it is mentioned that it has a max shutter speed of 1/4000. I want to use atleast 1/1500.

Please let me know how can I get this?

Comment: Welcome to Photo stack exchange. Don't forget to take the tour, review the help, and surf around. We hope your visit here is informative, and fun.

Answer (score 3):

If your only goal is to use the maximum shutter speed, it likely will choose that speed under very brightly lit conditions (I.e. Outdoors on a sunny day).

Another option is to look for a scene mode in the camera such as "Action" or "Sports" and that likely would use it as well.

Comment: Setting the ISO to the lowest value, if that is user delectable, should also help.

Comment: @MichaelClark for a faster shutter I think you mean *higher* ISO, don't you?

Comment: @scottbb Yes. Yes I do.

Comment: Hehe "User Delectable" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Other possible hack, based on the User Manual:

> Motion detection Allows you to set whether or not the camera
>   automatically increases the shutter speed to reduce blurring caused by
>   camera shake when motion is detected when shooting still images.

And as the comments suggest, set the ISO setting as high as you can without inducing noise. The camera will speed up the shutter to match.